# Can I programmatically determine the health of the ReplSet (Java Driver)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am wondering if I can programmatically determine the health of the Replset through the Mongo Java Driver.  What I want to know is:  Where is the PRIMARY?  How "caught up" are the SECONDARIES in oplog time?  Is this possible and what's the API to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.command("ismaster").get("primary") : Gives you the current primary

db.getSisterDB("admin").command("replSetGetStatus").get("members") : It contains the necessary replication details for all the members. This command has to run over admin database

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is very promising, thanks.  I'll see if I can leverage this.

Comment: Wow.  That works pretty well:  CommandResult result = mongo.getDB( "admin" ).command( "replSetGetStatus" ); System.out.println( "members: " + result.get( "members" ) );